# How to save a Docker container state

Tags: docker

I'm trying to learn the ins and outs of Docker, and I'm confused by the prospect of saving an image.

I ran the basic Ubuntu image, installed Anaconda Python and a few other things...so now what's the best way to save my progress? Save, commit, export?

None of these seem to work the same way as VirtualBox, which presents an obvious save-state file for your virtual machine.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The usual way is at least through a [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/): that will freeze the state of your container into a new image.

Note: As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480740/how-to-saving-a-docker-container-state/44480870#comment78796162_44480870) by [anchovylegend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316524/anchovylegend), this is not the best practice, and using a Dockerfile allows you to formally modeling the image content and ensure you can rebuild/reproduce its initial state.

You can then list that image locally with [`docker images`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/), and run it again.

Example:

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS              NAMES
c3f279d17e0a        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago          Up 25 hours                            desperate_dubinsky
197387f1b436        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago          Up 25 hours                            focused_hamilton

$ docker commit c3f279d17e0a  svendowideit/testimage:version3

f5283438590d

$ docker images

REPOSITORY                        TAG                 ID                  CREATED             SIZE
svendowideit/testimage            version3            f5283438590d        16 seconds ago      335.7 MB
```

---

After that, [if you have deployed a registry server](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/), you can push your image to said server.

Comment: While this will work, this approach is considered poor practice by the Docker community. Best way to go is using a Dockerfile.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend I agree and have edited the answer to include your comment and make that clear.

Comment: The dockerfile reproduces the install of programs, but what if you're then loading data in the database for instance, the dockerfile won't be saving that state in any way right?

Comment: @chrismarx it might, but an image should not be used to store information that will be changed on runtime like a database). Said information should be accessed through a volume.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the right way for production for sure. But many of us are just using docker locally as a slimmed down version of virtualbox, and just want the damn state saved, exactly as is. And don't want extra volumes on our local drives either

Comment: While I already knew this is considered bad practice, I just discovered it extremely useful for keeping what I just did in a little (3h) workshop on some piece of software I had quickly spun up in a container.

Comment: I think this gave me problems because of the forward-slash "`/`".

Comment: Is it better to do this while the container is on or off?

Comment: @Nathan Depending on the nature of the data accessed by the process running in that container, stopping the container first is more sensible.

Comment: My sincere apologies to the docker team, but I am sticking with `docker commit` and `docker save `. That's all I need. Thank you.

Comment: @FractalSpace Then maybe you would also want to try Apptainer/Singularity out.

Answer (score 7):

The usual way is at least through a docker commit: that will freeze the state of your container into a new image.

But know that there is no reliable way to "save state" of container unlike virtual machine save state in Hyper-V or VMware. This is a downside also to docker.

It seems it only saves the changes made to the persistent file changes. So when you spin up the container again from new images, the dependencies and all the run commands executed will not have same effect.

That's why its ideal to have to changes in docker file and in short, there is no save state feature in docker system like we have in virtual machines. The memory contents are always lost.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible (*but not recommended*) by using `docker commit` command.
You can check the following clear example:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-commit-changes-to-docker-image

Comment: i have a case where I must use commit; because I have a system that can't be totally scripted.  you need to get in and push a bunch of buttons to get it into the right state.  i have to deal with that situation..

Comment: @Rob I totally understand your case, however, in an ideal DevOps automated environment, it is better to avoid `manual intervention` as possible

Comment: I can't.  somebody wrote something stupid.  and another person demanded that I use it.

Comment: So, you can automate it by getting containers into the state you want manually, and committing it.

Comment: Posting links to blogs which might be removed from the internet someday is not an ideal answer.  Better to provide the actual details of your answer here.

Answer (score -2):

Use a Docker file for these kind of scenarios.

An example case for an Ubuntu image with MongoDB:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Author name

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
RUN echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist    10gen" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils
RUN apt-get -y install mongodb-10gen

#RUN echo "" >> /etc/mongodb.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--config", "/etc/mongodb.conf"]
```

Also see *[Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)*.

Comment: Down-voted because this does not answer the question.  Besides, all changes to the mongodb database on this image will be lost when the image is reloaded.