# Restoring the state of docker containers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, restore, ca

I have a docker container in a hyperledger fabric setup. This stores all user credentials.
What happens if this container or machine goes down and is not available?
If I bring up a backup container, how can the entire state be restored?

I tried doing the commit option but on bringing it back up, it does not work as expected. More likely the CA functionality uses some container id to track since a CA server is highly secretive price of the setup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save a Docker container State?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480740/how-to-save-a-docker-container-state)

Answer (score 0):

Overall, this is more of a strategy question, there are many approaches to backing up critical data - and you may or may not choose one that is specific to Docker containers.

On the technical questions that you asked:

If the container 'goes down', its files remain intact and will be there when it is restarted (that is, if you re-start the same container and don't create a new one). If the machine goes down, the container will come 'back up' if and when the machine is restarted. Depending on how you created the container, you may need to start it yourself or Docker may restart it automatically. If it went down hard and won't come back - you lose all data on it, including files in containers.

You can create a 'backup container' (or more precisely, a backup image), but if it was left on the same machine it will die with that machine. You will need to save it elsewhere (e.g., with 'docker push', though I don't recommend that unless you have your own docker registry to use for backups).

If you do 'commit', this simply creates a new container image, which has the files as they were when you did the commit. You should commit a stopped container, if you want a proper copy of all files - I don't think you can do it while there are active open files. This copy lives on the same machine where the container was, so you still need to save it away from that machine to protect it from loss. Note that to use the saved image, you should tag it and use it to start a new container. The image from which you started the old container is untouched by the 'commit' (using that old image will start the container as it was then, when you first created it).

IMO, an option better than 'commit' (which saves the entire container file system, along with all the junk like logs and temp. files) is to mount a docker volume to the path where important files are stored (e.g., /var/lib/mysql, if you run a mysql database) - and back up only that volume.