# Can we create Image from docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, containers, devops

Can we create Image from docker container ?

I have to create a container with jenkins with RBAS plugin with some roles.
Can I create a container with base jenkins image and install the plugins and roles on the UI and convert/create the jenkins container to image.

Comment: Please be more specific in your questions. Provide details, what have you tried and found and then the community can help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a Docker container state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480740/how-to-save-a-docker-container-state)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is at least through a [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/).

That will freeze the state of your container into a new image.
*Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480740/how-to-save-a-docker-container-state)*.

---

**HOWEVER**: I doubt it's trivial to make it the way you want using an UI (but I haven’t tried it yet). Docker does not provide "out-of-the-box graphical user interfaces". As far as I know it's somehow possible, but that requires some setup and does not guarantee to work.

---

*Edit*: I guess I read your question wrong. I think you meant using "Jenkin's UI" (the Web Interface). In this case this is totally possible.

Comment: `docker commit` leads to images that are hard to reproduce or recreate.  In the context of this question, if you commit an image, and a year later discover that there was a critical security issue in the base Jenkins installation, there's no way to update it without starting over.  The standard Dockerfile system is much more maintainable, and I'd recommend avoiding `docker commit` if at all possible.

Comment: I totally agree with you and I would also not recommend anyone to use it, if no necessary. But still I think there are some good reason to use it in combination with Jenkins. Jenkins can have a complex setup process (credentials, pipelines and more) which can not be automated easily and I it‘s understandable to do the process using the UI and then just commit the Image to use it later. Also, the author specifically asked for this.