# Docker: How to transfer container with data from one host to another

Tags: docker

for testing purposes with databases i need to transfer a mysqlsql container with database data to another host by usb stick.

I ran into trouble by using a data volume. it work fine locally but it is not simple to deploy to another host.

Is there a simple way to exchage container with data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a Docker container state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480740/how-to-save-a-docker-container-state)

Comment: I'm almost tempted to say that you should always create new containers and never port existing, since there are many environment variables (network/hostname/available resources) that might differ between hosts. Basically, Docker was designed specifically with this in mind. In your case, would it not be easier to migrate "just" the data (i.e. db dump and restore)?